# How to know if a row exists or not in parse data

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I pushed an object to parse database.Now I want to push one more data object to the row but I want that if the same set of values already exists than it should not push the object but refresh the object with new values.
Lets I have 3 colums rollnum,name and city.If the same roll num is pushed,the particular row with available roll number in the parse data will upload the new values.
I tried this:

```
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery
                    .getQuery("StudentInfo");
            query.whereEqualTo("rollnum", rollnum.getText()
                    .toString());
            query.whereEqualTo("name", name.getText()
                    .toString());
            query.whereEqualTo("city", city.getText().toString());
            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject obj, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This Information already exists..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    else{

                        obj = new ParseObject(
                                "StudentInfo");
                        obj.put("rollnum", rollnum.getText()
                                .toString());
                        obj.put("name",name.getText()
                                .toString());
                        obj.put("city", city.getText().toString());
                        obj.saveInBackground();



                    }

                }

            });
```

Comment: What is the outcome of the the code you have given?

Comment: Sorry I tried to do this but at a point I got confused and didn't understand.It is the dummy code.I wanted this to work like I asked but I was not able to understand how to do

Answer (score 0):

If the object does not exist then nothing will be in your return object, error does not indicate an object does not exist, all that indicates is that something went wrong when trying to get your data

also your `done` method is wrong, it should look like this

```
public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
```

all you do is check the data

```
if(objects != null && objects.count > 0){
    // I have data here!!!
}
```

Comment: Should I have to remove ParseQuery Or it will be there for satisfying the requirements to get the exact obect

Comment: Sorry it is pushing new objects and I want if the object already exists it should update the old object with new values

Comment: what!? a query does not create new objects, that makes no sense. please read the documentation https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries

Comment: if(objects != null && objects.count > 0)  i am doing nothing but if its not true I am pushing the object with object.put().

Comment: if objects has a count that means you foudn what you are looking for so do what you want there

Comment: I used your method and there is a row satisfying the requirements but still its giving me exception e as null.

Comment: i am not getting why e is null as there is a row with the same values I am filling in.

Comment: why would e not be null there is no exception being thrown, do you know what an exception is aka error?

Comment: Oh I am sorry I got it.I meant it is not fetching any row  :)

Comment: I am using query.findInBackground() method for fetching rows from parse